# How to remove '13 from the corfu-map?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, corfu

I am using `corfu`. Problem is that when I type something like "isearch" and want to continue with a new line and not to invoke a popup command.

When the `corfu` popup is open and suggesting `isearch-cmds`, `isearch-face`, ... and I hit `ENTER` Emacs does not start a new line. Instead it selects `isearch-cmds` from the `corfu` popup and inserts it.

When looking into `corfu-map` I see this:

```lisp
(keymap
 (return)
 (ret)
 (67109092 . corfu-quit)
 (9 . corfu-complete)
 (13 . corfu-insert)
 (7 . corfu-quit)
 (27 keymap
     (100 . corfu-popupinfo-toggle)
     (32 . corfu-insert-separator)
     (104 . corfu-info-documentation)
     (103 . corfu-info-location)
     (112 . corfu-popupinfo-scroll-down)
     (110 . corfu-popupinfo-scroll-up))
 (tab . corfu-complete)
 (up . corfu-previous)
 (down . corfu-next)
 (remap keymap
        (keyboard-escape-quit . corfu-reset)
        (completion-at-point . corfu-complete)
        (previous-line . corfu-previous)
        (next-line . corfu-next)
        (scroll-up-command . corfu-scroll-up)
        (scroll-down-command . corfu-scroll-down)
        (end-of-buffer . corfu-last)
        (beginning-of-buffer . corfu-first)))
```

I think the `13` is the `ENTER` key and it is bound to `corfu-insert`.

So how do I remove the `13` entry from `corfu-map` so that hitting `ENTER` inserts a new line instead of invocing the command.

Answer (score 2):

The question is likely a duplicate. Please search and if so, delete it.

```lisp
(define-key corfu-map (kbd "<RET>") nil)
```

Comment: What seems to overwrite the keymap? In what way? All this code does is remove the `RET` binding for `corfu-map`. Whatever other binding `RET` has currently should then be in effect. The question, as I read it, is how to remove the binding of `RET` to `corfu-insert`. I answered that, I think.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, Drew is right. It seems that you can overwrite the keymap if you specify some function other than nil.

Comment: If nil, the original function remains.

Comment: Confusingly this code adds `(return)` to the map but the `13` is not removed. But it has the desired effect!

Comment: @Witek: Really? What does `M-: (kbd "<RET>") RET` tell you? Does it tell you `[return]`? For me it returns `"^M"`; that is, a string with the single character Control M, which is 13.

Comment: @Witek: If something like that is the case for you, try this instead: `(define-key corfu-map [?
] nil)`, where after typing `?` you type `C-q C-m`. (Instead of seeing a space char you should see a Control M char after the `?`.)

Answer (score 0):

How about overriding the called function `corfu-insert`? This overriden function just put a linefeed unless you tab-complete or move up/down to select.

```lisp
(eval-after-load 'corfu
  '(defun corfu-insert ()
     (interactive)
     (if (> corfu--index 0) ;; was: >=0
         (corfu--insert 'finished) ;; original behavior
       (insert-char ?\n)))) ;; only put linefeed as you wish
```